# How can I disable checking the NTFS file system when booting the system?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, ntfs, boot, check-disk

Windows Vista SP2 and Win7:

After the BIOS gets done posting, CHKNTFS checks the NTFS file system before proceeding to login. I would like to disable CHKNTFS, as this makes the boot process very long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had no problem disabling CHKNTFS for Drive C: with the /X option, however, CHKNTFS was still checking a hidden OEM partition with no visible DRIVE or volume name, so I wasn't able to disable it with /X.

Therefore, I had to modify the `BootExecute` registry value to `autocheck autochk /k:*` in order to disable all partitions, including the hidden one (see image below).

BTW, this tweak is done the same way for Win7.

[image]

Comment: BTW, if any of the partitions has problems, Windows will trap this exception and execute CHKNTFS to attempt to repair them. My laptop now gets to the login screen within 9 seconds from the time I power it up. You can manually run CHKNTFS whenever you choose to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you have to do `CHKNTFS /X Your_Drive` in command prompt, on next boot it won't check.

The X tells Windows to NOT check that particular drive on the next reboot.

Comment: That works fine for NTFS un-hidden partitions with logical drive designations, however virtually all laptop's like mine have a hidden OEM partition, (PQSERVICE for Acer's), which is used for Recovery and CHKNTFS doesn't support these with the /X option. So, I had to tweak a registry value to work around this limitation (See my answer below).